# Is there a way to prevent iron-router from trying to route a link?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have my Meteor app running in a subfolder and the rest of my domain is still running on Wordpress. I need a specific link in my meteor app to go to a path on Wordpress.

So the meteor app is here
https://domain.com/meteor

Wordpress is here
https://domain.com

And my link path looks like this
https://domain.com/WPLink

If I click the https://domain.com/WPLink from within the Meteor app Iron-router tries to send it to my default route of /meteor, but this isn't where it should be going.

Any idea how I can make sure Iron-router isn't trying to route that link?

Comment: Root url for meteor is domain.com/meteor so i dont think you can access WP from meteor ( but I might be wrong ) . I would create a template wp_link with 'a hreg="http://domain.com" ' and whenever id need it id just render it {{>wp_link}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In older versions of `iron-router` you would do something like:

```
IronLocation.configure({
  'linkSelector' : 'a[href]:not([noroute])',
});
```

Though, I am not 100% sure if this will work in `1.0`.

Comment: Anywhere on the client.